# how to get errors or a custom form validation to send alert

Tags: angular

I have code that will validate if two date inputs are at least 1 year apart in my form.

Here is how I do it;

```
        validateDates(group: ControlGroup) {

        var valid=false;
        var startdate: any;
        var enddate: any;
        for (name in group.controls) {
            var val = group.controls[name].value;
            if (name=='startdate'){startdate=val; }
            if (name=='enddate'){enddate=val;}
        }

        var diff:any;
        diff = new Date(enddate).valueOf() - new Date(startdate).valueOf();
        console.log(diff);
        if (diff>=31622400000){
            valid = true;
        }
        if (valid) {return null; }
        return {validateDates: true};
    }

this.form = fb.group({
            estimationmethod: [''],
            lambda: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,ModelValidators.validLambda])],
            overlayvolitilities: [''],
            dateRangeValidate: fb.group({
                startdate: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,ModelValidators.validStartDate])],
                enddate: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,ModelValidators.validEndDate])],
            }, {validator: this.validateDates})

        });
```

Now the code does work but I want to display message if not valid.

E.g. for end date these alerts show if error:

```
<div *ngIf="enddate.touched && enddate.errors">
                                <div *ngIf="enddate.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger">
                                    End Date is required.
                                </div>
                                <div *ngIf="enddate.errors.validEndDate" class="alert alert-danger">
                                    Date must be less then today
                                </div>
                   </div>
```

The above works but I cant get the daterange test.
For the testing if start and end date are valid..how do I get the error?

e.g.

```
<div *ngIf="form.dateRangeValidate.errors" class="alert alert-danger">
```

Comment: What doesn't not work with the code in the last line of your question?

Comment: I did it to work by using this - *ngIf="!form.controls.dateRangeValidate.valid"